# not able change textures on click threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am trying to change textures / colors of an object onclick (by clicking on separate cubes )

I'm able to change the color of an object only once (even though i use a for-loop ) and provided that no previous textures or colors on the object.
However, I'm not able to change the color if the object already has an existing color.
Do i need to add some needsUpdate ? I did but no luck.. please have a look on my onclick function.

```
EventsControls.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
    var colors = ['White', 'blue', 'gold'];
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                if (child.material.name == "Sofa_Leather") {
                    child.material = colors[i]; // array elements are already defined
                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                    child.material.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                    child.material.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Kindly let me know where 'im going wrong. Thank you.

//retried but could manage to change only one color with the below code, i think im using the needsUpdate in a wrong way.

```
                    var index=0;    
                    var colors=[0xfffeef,0xffff00,0x000fff];

                     object.traverse( function( child ) { if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                    if (child.material.name == "Sofa_Leather")  {

                                 if(index == colors.length) index = 0;
                                 child.material.color.setHex(colors[index++]);

                                child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                                child.receiveShadow = true;
                            } }
                     })
```

Comment: material isn't equal to a color?did you try `material.color` but it should be in correct color format like `0xff0000`.

Comment: var White = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
 color:0xffffef,
 combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation,
 reflectivity:0.4
})  
i have defined colors globally like this, i tried using material.color = colors[i], but object disappears when onclicked

Comment: You seem to be setting color to a string, try using the method: .setHex(0xff0000); See this example - http://jsfiddle.net/Lfr5my2s/11/

Comment: His problem may be that he is trying to reference `i` within a closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this by using:

```
material.color.setHex(0xffffff * Math.random()); // set to random color
```

**EDIT:**

Well yeah sure you can do this also:

```
var colors = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff]; // red, green and blue
if(index == colors.length) index = 0;
line.material.color.setHex(colors[index++]);
```

See this *updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfr5my2s/12/)*

Comment: Neil, im able to do this,  but my requirement is i need selected colors/ textures stored in an array, so that i can use them onclick accordingly.

Comment: @andyram I don't see a problem, see updated answer and fiddle

Comment: i retried it with the fiddle reference, i could manage to pull in first array color, but not all, is it a needsupdate problem here ? I have updated the code above.